# Image Normalization In Python

Tags: python, image, normalization

The image file is as follows:

```
file = misc.imread("....\image_123.png")
Image.fromarray(file,'L')
```

[image]

```
file.shape
(600, 600)
```

Range of pixel values in the file:

```
print ("min = %s, max = %s"% (np.min(file1), np.max(file1)))
min = 0, max = 239
```

I want to apply a standard normalization like subtract 255/2 from the pixel values and divide by 255

```
file_mod = (file.astype(float) - 255/2)/255
```

Next when I try to visualize the normalized image I see a completely distorted output:

[image]

Even something like below distorts the image:

```
file_mod = (file.astype(float) - 0.0)/1.0
```

Please help with the process of standard normalization methods.

Comment: `"standard normalization like subtract 255/2 from the pixel values and divide by 255"` that is not a standard normalization technique, [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)).

Comment: hm, curious what happens if you use the imshow function from matplotlib. E.g., `plt.imshow(file_mod, cmap='binary')`